# Write a string to a Stream without additional intermediate buffer creation

Tags: .net, string, stream

I have a `string` and want to write it to a `Stream` instance. Given that I don't want to wrap the stream in a `StreamWriter`, as non-string data is also written to that same stream, the probably easiest way is this:

```
byte[] bytes = myEncoding.GetBytes(string);
stream.Write(bytes 0, bytes.Length);
```

This is in a very performance-critical part of my program, and I'd like to avoid the unnecessary creation of the intermediate byte array. Can it be done in .net without reimplementing the string encoding functionality of the `System.Text` namespace?

Using [Encoder.Convert(Char[], Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32, Int32, Boolean, Int32, Int32, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh0797c4.aspx), which I could theoretically loop over with my own reused `Byte[]` array doesn't look like the most efficient way to do it, although it would probably be more efficient than the `Encoding.GetBytes` variant.

So is there any direct way to write a string to a Stream that I'm missing?

Comment: You obviously can write as sequence of characters - no encoding is needed... But you really should make sure you have performance goals and measure your code to see if it achieve the goals. Chances are stream's destination is so much slower than any code you can write that performance of string conversion does not matter at all...

Comment: Characters are not bytes. So how would you write a sequence of characters to a byte stream, without intermediate buffers? I do agree that you need to profile to determine whether there's any point in optimizing any particular piece of code, and I'm doing that.

Comment: `stream.WriteByte(char && 0xff);stream.WriteByte(char >> 8)`...

Comment: Your code assumes I want the output to be in `UTf-16`, which might differ from `myEncoding`. In fact, for the problem at hand, I need UTF-8, but I do not want to go as low level as having to tinker with UTF-8 encoding details. Also, I'm trying to figure out a general solution.